# Loop over list of years

Tags: python, list, date, for-loop

I want to loop over a list of years and compute a national holiday that varies by date every year. I have come across some libraries that I can use for this, but I fail to implement them for all years in a for-loop.

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.easter import easter
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rd

#range of years I want to compute this date for
year = list(range(2008,2019))

for i in year:
    e = easter(year)
    maundy_thursday = e - rd(days=3)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-1691b0469173> in <module>
      2 
      3 for i in year:
----> 4     e = easter(year)
      5     maundy_thursday = e - rd(days=3)
      6     good_friday = e - rd(days=2)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\easter.py in easter(year, method)
     64 
     65     y = year
---> 66     g = y % 19
     67     e = 0
     68     if method < 3:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: ``i`` is your year, ``year`` is your list-of-years. maybe pick better variable names.

Comment: A good argument for better variable names. `year` should probably be named `years` which would make this typo easier to see. Then you could say `for year in years:`

Comment: maybe read up on conventions and etc to get better at naming variables :)

Comment: To be fair, naming things is proverbially one of the hardest things in computing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have confusion between variables, ultimately caused by misleading names.

You have:

```
year = list(range(2008,2019))

for i in year:
    e = easter(year)
```

Notice that you pass the `year` variable to the `easter()` function, but this is in fact the list of years.

What you meant:

```
years = list(range(2008,2019))

for year in years:
    e = easter(year)
```

As a side-note, you don't need the `list()` here; you can write: `years = range(2008, 2019)`